# Parallax Footer

Tags: html, css, footer, parallax

I'm trying to create a parallax footer for my [website](http://globallabs.de)

The problem that i have is that it wont' work as i would like to have it. I'm given the main container `.elementor .elementor-8` the following styles

```
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
```

The footer with the class `.elementor-location-footer` get those one

```
position: fixed;
z-index: -1;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
```

Normally it should work, but when i give the footer the position fixed its gone. How could i fix it ?

[image: Thats what i'm trying to build]

Comment: Yours works - https://jsfiddle.net/mdLfrk2p/1/

Comment: but why not on my website ?

Comment: dunno, send more of your code